# How can I find out which generation my iPod belongs to?

Tags: ipod

I have a iPod Classic 160 Gb. I have forgotten the generation. Is there any way by which I can find out the generation of the iPod?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1353

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Apple's note on identifying which iPod model](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1353) you have.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [MacTracker](http://mactracker.ca/).  It's a free app with information on pretty much everything that Apple has ever made.

Comment: Well, I dont have a mac, but thanks. It looks like an interesting SW.